# Predict using a ranger model

Tags: r, r-caret

I have the following code:

```
tc <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                   number = 5 ,
                   repeats = 5, 
                   summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, 
                   classProbs = TRUE,
                   verboseIter = TRUE)

model <- train(class ~ .
               , data=myData 
               , trControl=tc
               , method="ranger"
               , metric="ROC"
               , importance = 'impurity'
               )
```

This produces a model which I would like to use to predict unseen data points. The following works correctly:

```
predict(model,myData)
```

It produces a list of results which is exactly what i want. However I will be using the model on single row samples in future (There will be user input that will be used to create a prediction). So to test this is did the following:

```
predict(model,myData[1,])
```

, and get the following error.

> Error in apply(out, 1, which.max) : dim(X) must have a positive length

If I change the code to be:

```
predict(model, myData[1:2,])
```

,I again get results.

It seems like the predict function and the ranger model does not play nicely when there is only one row in the input data set. Or, I am doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please remember to provide a reproducible example including the data